# UITableviewcell with UIbutton , changes tableview cell background color

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have added custom `UITableViewCell` with `UIButton`. On button click I have added popup but whenever I clicked on button  then `UITableViewCell` background color will changed. I don't want to change the color. Also add `UITableViewSelectionStyleNone`.

**Screenshot:**
 [image]

Comment: where did you add UITableViewSelectionStyleNone

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: set `UITableViewSelectionStyleNone` in cell's class.

Comment: Added background color to white instead of clear color to cell solves my problem. Thanks to all .

Answer (score -1):

Set `UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle` to `.none` if using swift or 
`UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` for Objective-C. Also try